# MongoDB connection abnormal increase

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongodb client to connect Database like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nDEG.png). Notice, i only use one connect to DB, but when i start my application and check Mongodb connection by command.

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

Before start app at 8 connection, after it increase more 20 connection. I miss something, any one help me to explain ?